# How to add visited pages urls into a session array?

Tags: php

Everytime the user visit a page, the page url will be stored into an array session. I want to have 10 elements in the array only. So that 10 elements will save 10 latest visited page urls. Here is my codes :

```
<?php
$currentpageurl = $_GET['username'];

$urlarray=array();

$urlarray[] = $currentpageurl;

$_SESSION['pageurl']=$urlarray;

foreach($_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
?>
```

I tested the code, it always overwrite the element in the array with new visited page, thus it has only 1 element in the array. How to make it not to overwrite the element?

Comment: actually i just want to save the user profile pages url, and each of the url are the same at begening, just the username is different, so i just need to save the username.

Comment: OK. Seems like a strange choice of variable name, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always overwriting the array with a new one here:

```
$urlarray=array();       // new empty array
$urlarray[] = $currentpageurl;    
$_SESSION['pageurl']=$urlarray;
```

Instead use:

```
session_start();
// like @Kwpolska said, you probably miss that, so $_SESSION didnt work

is_array($_SESSION["pageurl"]) or $_SESSION["pageurl"] = array();
// fix for your current problem

$_SESSION['pageurl'][] = $currentpageurl;
// This appends it right onto an array.

$_SESSION["pageurl"] = array_slice($_SESSION["pageurl"], -10);
// to cut it down to the last 10 elements
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. It still overwrite the existing elements after i did as what you suggested.

Comment: Is it because session fail to send the value to other page since the url of the page is change from testing18.php?username=zac1987 to testing18.php?username=abc123

Comment: You likely miss the session_start, like Kwpolska said. See the update for a workaround to your problem (string already exists in that position). Otherwise you have some other code, or didn't remove yours, which overwrites the entry invalidly.

Comment: @mario, thank you so much!!! Your codes work perfectly. Anyway, I don't really understand the codes "//fix for your current problem", is that what the codes do is checking whether or not $_SESSION["pageurl"] is an array? If it is not an array, then make $_SESSION["pageurl"] become an array?

Comment: @zac1987: Yes. That's exactly what it does. It's just another way to write an `if` check btw.

Comment: @mario I'm getting a "Notice: Undefined index: pageurl" error on the first page visit, but everything works fine when I refresh or visit more pages. Any idea how to get the error to go away?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do this and keep just the last 10 entries will be to create your initial array with the correct size (via array_fill()). Then we can push new items onto the beginning of the array and pop old items off the other end using array_unshift() and array_pop().

```
session_start();

// Initialise URL array with 10 entries.
if (empty($_SESSION['pageurls'])) {
    $_SESSION['pageurls'] = array_fill(0,10,'');
}

function trackPage($url) {
    array_unshift($_SESSION['pageurls'],$url);
    array_pop($_SESSION['pageurls']);
}
```

Make sure the above code always runs first. Then you can pass new URLs to the array when you want. So, perhaps something like:

```
trackPage($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: Cool stuff! Learn a new things from you. Thank you GENIUS CVM.

Answer (score -1):

You've ommitted `session_start();`.  Working code (without trimming):

```
<?php
session_start();
$currentpageurl = $_GET['username'];
$_SESSION['pageurl'][] = $currentpageurl;

foreach($_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Its give errors Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\wamp\www\plekz\testing18.php on line 12

Comment: Get a better webserver.  It worked fine on php5 with debian lenny.  You can find another way to put it to an array.

Comment: -1 You should have initialised `$_SESSION['pageurl']` to `Array()` when it's not already set. You're relying on low warning/notice levels. And "well you can just find another way to do it then" is not particularly helpful, is it?