# How to show a users last visited pages in wp / buddypress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, buddypress

im trying to figure out how i can show the last 3-5 or so pages within my site a person has visited. I did some searching, and I couldn't find a WP plugin that does so, if anyone knows of one, please point me in that direction :) if not, I'll have to write it from scratch, and thats where i'll need the help.

I've been trying to understand the DB and how it works. I'm assuming that this is where the magic will happen, with PHP, unless there is a javascript option using cookies to do it.

Im open to all ideas :P & Thank you

Comment: have you ceheck this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754957/how-to-add-visited-pages-urls-into-a-session-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i were to code such a plugin, i'd use the session cookies to populate an array via array_unshift() and array_pop().  it'd be as simple as :

```
$server_url = "http://mydomain.com";
$current_url = $server_url.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$history_max_url = 5; // change to the number of urls in the history array

//Assign _SESSION array to variable, create one if empty ::: Thanks to Sold Out Activist for the explanation!
$history = (array) $_SESSION['history'];

//Add current url as the latest visit
array_unshift($history, $current_url);
//If history array is full, remove oldest entry
if (count($history) > $history_max_url) {
    array_pop($history);
}
//update session variable
$_SESSION['history']=$history;
```

Now i've coded this on the fly.  There might be syntax errors or typos.  If such a mistake appears, just put a notice and i'll modify it.  The purpose of this answer is mostly to make a proof of concept.  You can adapt this to your liking.  Please note that i assume that session_start() is already in your code.

Hope it helps.

===============

Hey! Sorry about the late answer, i was out of town for a couple of days! :)

This addon is to answer your request for a print out solution with LI tags

Here's what i'd do :

```
print "<ol>";
foreach($_SESSION['history'] as $line) {
     print "<li>".$line.</li>";
}
print "</ol>";
```

Simple as that.  you should read the foreach loop here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

As for the session_start();, put it before you use any $_SESSION variables.

Hope it helped! :)

Comment: No one ever remembers PHP's dynamic variables. "$history = (array) $_SESSION['history'];" skips all that "if (count" jazz.

Comment: PHP automatically types variables based on its contents, regardless of what it was before. $test = 1 becomes a number, $test = "string" is now a string. You can help the typecasting along. $test = (string) 1 will be a string. "$history = (array) $_SESSION['history'];" casts the session variable to an array, if it's empty, PHP simply creates an empty array.

Comment: I knew we could declare arrays with array() but never came across the (array) syntax.  Crystal clear explanation, friend! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Due to PHP's dynamic typecasting, rarely does one need to use manual typecasting. In other languages, though, it's a daily occurrence. Here it is simply a shortcut to decrease logic gates and shave a few milliseconds off code execution.

Comment: Hey there! First off, Thanks for taking the time to answer me! I'm reading over the code trying to get an understanding of what exactly is going on. I'll have to admit though, i'm not sure where the session_start() goes, or whether it's initiated or not. Also, one more thing, Let's say i wanted this to print out in <li></li> tags, how would I go about that? I'm not very savvy in PHP, so please excuse me. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to update and translate the code above for WordPress 5+ because the original question has the `wordpress` tag. Note that you don't need `session_start()` anywhere.

Here it goes, add the code below to your `singular.php` template (or `single.php` + `page.php` templates, depending on what you need):

```php
/**
 * Store last visited ID (WordPress ID)
 */
function so7035465_store_last_id() {
    global $post;

    $postId = $post->ID; // or get the post ID from your template

    $historyMaxUrl = 3; // number of URLs in the history array
    $history = (array) $_SESSION['history'];

    array_unshift($history, $postId);

    if (count($history) > $historyMaxUrl) {
        array_pop($history);
    }

    $_SESSION['history'] = $history;
}

// Display latest viewed posts (or pages) wherever you want
echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($_SESSION['history'] as $lastViewedId) {
        echo '<li>' . get_permalink($lastViewedId) . '</li>';
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

You can also store latest viewed custom post types (CPT) by placing the `so7035465_store_last_id()` function in your `single-cpt.php` template.

You can also add it to a hook or inject it in your template as an action, but that is beyond the scope of this question.