# Create a page that shows a user which pages they have been to using PHP

Tags: php, list, tracker

I was wondering if there was a way to create a page on my website that would allow for a user to view the pages in the website that they have been to. I have searched around to see if I could find a hint to where I could start from, but I came up empty. I have already coded a system where a user can sign up and log in, I just need a way so that they can track where they have been. Thanks

Comment: sessions? cookies? <= with conditional statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add visited pages urls into a session array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754957/how-to-add-visited-pages-urls-into-a-session-array)

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into full detail, as I cannot comment to ask how you would prefer, but an example using sessions would be such;

At the start of each page, you could do something as follows;

```
session_start();
array_push($_SESSION['pages'], "`You would put a user-friendly page name here`");
```

Or alternatively;

```
session_start();
array_push($_SESSION['pages'], __FILE__);
```

The above would store each page the user visits in a session named pages. If you wanted to, for say, receive the last *five* visited pages, you could then do something as such;

```
array_slice($_SESSION['pages'], -5);
```

Although this wouldn't be the most efficient and/or is just basic, it is the bedrock in which you could expand upon.

Another idea would be to log the page visits to a database. You could have a table names page_views or similar with id, user identifier and page as the columns, then following the above example to 'log' the page views to the database. You could then select from the database and limit to the last 5 records matching the user identifier, therefor receiving the five latest logged pages.